# An inequality for $\lfloor x \rfloor- \lfloor y \rfloor$

Tags: inequality, ceiling-and-floor-functions

In wikipedia, I come across this identity for the floor function:

In my question, I am interested in $x,y>0$.
\begin{equation}
 \lfloor x \rfloor + \lfloor y \rfloor \leq \lfloor x + y \rfloor \leq \lfloor x \rfloor + \lfloor y\rfloor + 1.
\end{equation}

Now, making some substitutions I arrive at
\begin{equation}
 \lfloor x -  y \rfloor  \leq  \lfloor x \rfloor - \lfloor y \rfloor \leq \lfloor x -  y \rfloor + 1.
\end{equation}

However, I think that because of my positivity restriction, it is even stronger than that.
\begin{equation}
 \lfloor x -  y \rfloor  \leq  \lfloor x \rfloor - \lfloor y \rfloor < \lfloor x -  y \rfloor + 1.
\end{equation}
Is this true?

Or is there a case where we have equality
\begin{equation}\label{key}
 \lfloor x \rfloor - \lfloor y \rfloor = \lfloor x -  y \rfloor + 1,
\end{equation}
I suspect this is not possible, since the only possible `edge' cases are half integers. However, equality does not hold for such cases.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $x = 2, y = 1.5$, then
$$
\lfloor x \rfloor - \lfloor y \rfloor = 2 - 1 = 0 + 1 = \lfloor x - y \rfloor + 1.
$$